# Solve the following ODE : $x'(t)=\frac{3t^2+4t+2}{2x-2}$ condition $x(0)=-1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following question.

> Solve the following ODE $$x'(t)=\frac{3t^2+4t+2}{2x-2}, \qquad x(0)=-1$$

**This is what I did**

Using the relation of the integrals, I get :

$$\int_{-1}^{x(t)}(2s-2)ds = \int_{0}^{t} (3s^2+4s+2)ds $$

We get that : $$\int_{-1}^{x(t)}(2s-2)ds = (x(t))^2-2x(t)-3$$

$$\int_{0}^{t} (3s^2+4s+2)ds = t^3+2t^2+2t-2$$

So we get that $$(x(t))^2-2x(t)-3=t^3+2t^2+2t-2$$
$$(x(t)+1)(x(t)-3)=t(t(t+2)+1)-2$$

This is as far as I get, still I don't understand how can I get $x(t)=$?

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: That is not an equation. and certainly not an ODE. That's only an algebraic expression. What did you **actually** mean to write?

Comment: It's a separable ode, trying to find what is $x(t)$ I used the relation $\int_{x_0}^{x}\frac{1}{f(x)}=\int_{t_0}^{t} f(t)$

Comment: @Ja No, it's not. For something to aspire to be an equation there must be an equality sign...

Comment: Do you mean $$x'(t)=\frac{3t^2+4t+2}{2x-2}$$?

Comment: Good question, @Dr.SonnhardGraubner :)

Comment: @Don You'r right, my mistake.

Comment: @Dr Yes my bad sorry

Comment: It is $$x(t)=1\pm\sqrt{1+2t+2t^2+t^3+C}$$ by the hints above.

Comment: I have $(x(t))^2-2x(t)-3$ on one side, how to get rid of power of two? can you tell me the steps you made to reach this form of equation?

Comment: @JaVaPG Solve a quadratic equation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second integral has the wrong integration constant, note that the lower bound is at $t=0$,
$$
\int_{0}^t(3s^2+4s+2)ds=t^3+2t^2+2t
$$
there is no further constant.

Then complete the square in $x$
$$
(x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1=(x^2-2x-3)+4=t^3+2t^2+2t+4
$$
so that
$$
x(t)=1\pm\sqrt{t^3+2t^2+2t+4}
$$
and by the initial condition the solution is the minus branch,
$$
x(t)=1-\sqrt{t^3+2t^2+2t+4}
$$